# Selecting an option from a dropdown list causes react app to crash

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that is a select/ option that is populated from state. When the app renders for the first time, the dropdown list populates correctly, but when I select one of the options the app crashes and I get the error 'values.appOwner.map() is not a function. I am looking to populate this form and send it to my backend server. I want to pass the selected corporation to the backend. Here is my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

import { Image, Button, Badge } from 'antd';

const MobileAppCreateForm = ({
  handleSubmit,
  handleImage,
  handleChange,
  values,
  preview,
  uploadButtonText,
  handleImageRemove
}) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <form className='add-content-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div class='input-group'>
        <input
          type='text'
          className='form-control'
          placeholder='Mobile App Name'
          name='appName'
          value={values.appName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          style={{ marginRight: '.5rem' }}
        />
        <select
          title='Select Corporation'
          name='appOwner'
          className='form-select'
          value={values.appOwner}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <option selected>Select a Corporation</option>
          {values.appOwner &&
            values.appOwner.map(corp => (
              <option key={corp.corporationId} value={corp.corporationName}>
                {corp.corporationName}
              </option>
            ))}
        </select>
        <span
          class='input-group-text ant-btn-primary'
          style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
          onClick={e => router.push('/add_content/add_corporation')}
        >
          Add Corporation
        </span>
      </div>
      <div className='mb-3 mt-3'>
        <textarea
          className='form-control'
          rows='4'
          placeholder='Enter Mobile App Description'
          name='appDescription'
          value={values.appDescription}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-md-6'>
          <input
            type='text'
            className='form-control'
            placeholder='Mobile App Website'
            name='appWebsite'
            value={values.appWebsite}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className='col-md-6'>
          <input
            type='text'
            className='form-control'
            placeholder='Mobile App Privacy Policy Link'
            name='appPrivacyPolicyLink'
            value={values.appPrivacyPolicyLink}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='row mt-3'>
        <div className='col-md-4'>
          <select
            className='form-select'
            name='appUserAccountDownload'
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={values.appUserAccountDownload}
          >
            <option selected disabled>
              User Account Download
            </option>
            <option value='true'>True</option>
            <option value='false'>False</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className='col-md-4'>
          <select
            className='form-select'
            onChange={handleChange}
            name='appLocationHistory'
            value={values.appLocationHistory}
          >
            <option selected disabled>
              User Location History
            </option>
            <option value='true'>True</option>
            <option value='false'>False</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className='col-md-4'>
          <input
            type='text'
            className='form-control'
            placeholder='Mobile App Data Retention Length'
            name='appDataRetention'
            value={values.appDataRetention}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='row mt-3'>
        <div className='col-md-12'>
          <div className='form-group d-grid gap-2'>
            <label className='btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block text-start'>
              {uploadButtonText}
              <input
                type='file'
                name='image'
                onChange={handleImage}
                accept='image/*'
                hidden
              />
            </label>
            {preview && (
              <div style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
                <Badge
                  count='X'
                  onClick={handleImageRemove}
                  style={{
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: '5px',
                    right: '2px'
                  }}
                >
                  <Image width={200} src={preview} />
                </Badge>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='mb-3 mt-3'>
        <textarea
          className='form-control'
          rows='4'
          placeholder='iOS Associated Files'
          name='appIosAssociatedFiles'
          value={values.appIosAssociatedFiles}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div className='mb-3 mt-3'>
        <textarea
          className='form-control'
          rows='4'
          placeholder='iOS Associated Files'
          name='appAndroidAssociatedFiles'
          value={values.appAndoridAssociatedFiles}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </div>
      <Button
        type='submit'
        className='btn btn-primary ant-btn-primary'
        onClick={handleSubmit}
        disabled={values.loading || values.uploading}
        loading={values.loading}
        shape='round'
      >
        {values.loading ? 'Saving...' : 'Save'}
      </Button>

      <Button
        type='submit'
        className='btn btn-primary ant-btn-primary'
        disabled={values.loading || values.uploading}
        loading={values.loading}
        shape='round'
        style={{ marginLeft: '.25rem' }}
      >
        {values.loading ? 'Publishing...' : 'Publish'}
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default MobileAppCreateForm;
```

Here is my handleChange method:

```
const handleChange = (e, index) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
```

Comment: You bind the select to values.appOwner which makes me think it's a single object, not an array. Map is for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `values.appOwner` is not an array so you can't call `map()` on it. You could check if `appOwner` is actually and array instead of just checking if it's truthy (`{values.appOwner && ...`) since this condition would pass for a simple string or number and then would crash when calling `map` on it. You can use [Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to instead. You should still try to debug and see what's the actual value of `values.appOwner` to see why is not returning an array.

**Edit after adding handleChange function code**

The problem is with the `handleChange` method and also with the way you are handling state. You should use different objects to store the selected value and the initial options for the select. If you look at your code you are using `values.appOwner` both as the value prop in the `select` tag and as an array to iterate in to build the options. Once an option is selected you update `appOwner` with the selected value so it stops being an array.

Something like this could work

```
 const [corporation, setCorporation] = useState('');
 ....
   <select
      title='Select Corporation'
      name='appOwner'
      className='form-select'
      value={corporation}
      onChange={event => setCorporation(event.target.value)}
```

You might want to store the selected corporation in the parent component instead but the important thing here is that is separated from the `values.appOwner` piece

Comment: Rodrigo the results of Array.isArray() returns true. It is an array of Objects. It renders correctly on load. It is only when I select an item out of the list that it crashes.

Comment: That would indicate that the problem is actually with the `handleChange` method. What does it do? It might be changing the `value` prop in an incorrect way.

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo. It is somewhere in my handleChange method. I added it to my original post for comment.